# How to apply one effect over another in GPUImageView?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-gpuimageview

I am using GPUImageView to apply effects on images displayed on GPUImageView, I want to apply one effect over another, say I applied sepia effect first, then on top of that, I want to apply Contrast. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `GPUImageFilterGroup` object and add filters to it with `addFilter()`. After that you can apply the resulting filter to the `GPUImageView`. For example:

```
GPUImageView mImageView;

private void applyFilters(float contrast, float brightness) {
    GPUImageFilterGroup filterGroup = new GPUImageFilterGroup();
    filterGroup.addFilter(new GPUImageContrastFilter(contrast));
    filterGroup.addFilter(new GPUImageBrightnessFilter(brightness));

    mImageView.setFilter(filterGroup);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arkadiy. It helped me to do my task.